# Selecting users from table with one occurence

Tags: mysql

I have a table orders:

```
|--------------------|-----------------|------------|
|      user_id       |    article_id   |  Name      |
|--------------------|-----------------|------------|
|         1          |         39      |  John      |
|         1          |         39      |  John      |
|         2          |         39      |  Mike      |
|         2          |         19      |  Mike      |
|         3          |         39      |  Dave      |
|--------------------|-----------------|------------|
```

How can I select only those users who have article_id = 39, regardless of how many times, but if it occurs only once.
I would need to select user John and user Dave, but not Mike. Mike has article_id 39, but he also has article_id = 19.
The query should return users John and Dave.

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM orders AS o where o.article_id = 39
GROUP BY o.user_id HAVING COUNT(o.article_id) > 0
```

But it return all three users. I don't need user Mike.

Comment: You could use a join (once you've normalised your data)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT user_id, Name
FROM orders
GROUP BY user_id, Name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN article_id <> 39 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Note: Your table is not normalized, and the user information belongs in a separate user table.  I was able to get around this by including the name in the `GROUP BY` clause, but rightfully we should just be aggregating by the `user_id`.

Comment: It is normalized. User data is on separate table, I just included name column for clarity sake :)

Answer (score 3):

Tim's answer above is the most efficient way to get what you're looking for. Another solution to this is to use a nested query.

First, you select all users who don't have article_id 39:

```
SELECT user_id FROM orders WHERE article_id <> 39
```

Then select users who have an article_id of 39 that are not in this list. Overall, the query would be:

```
SELECT user_id FROM orders WHERE article_id = 39 
AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id from orders where article_id <> 39)
```

Again, the answers already posted by Tim and John are more efficient and better practice. I just find queries written like this easier to read/understand when learning SQL.

Comment: Well written +1 ... and there may be situations where this approach is preferable over an aggregation query.

Comment: I'd like to see some evidence of the relative efficiency of these solutions. Do you have any?

Comment: Perhaps, it was too general a statement to make, that this solution wouldn't be as efficient. Regarding evidence, I don't have any. It was just my understanding that nested queries should be avoided if possible. Maybe I am wrong in this. There are [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477340/performance-of-nested-select) that discuss the performance of nested queries in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, is to use `MIN()` and `MAX()`

```
SELECT  user_id
FROM    orders
GROUP   BY Name
HAVING  MIN(article_id) = MAX(article_id)
        AND MIN(article_id) = 39
```